# Почему не получается работать с cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Начал разбираться в работе с cookie и подобным вещам в js. Вроде все ясно но когда я повторяю то что написано в интернете у меня ничего не получается, вот просто пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>cookieTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.cookie= 'key3=val3;';
alert(document.cookie);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Я записываю в куки определенную строку и пытаюсь ее получить. Но почему то в alert ничего не выводиться, вообще ничего. Тоже самое когда пытаюсь вывести в консоль.

P.S:
Проверял это в браузерах: internet explorer, google chrome, yandex.
И вывелось в итоге вообще только в одном браузере на моем macbook, и это был safari..
Попытался на маке тоже повыводить через другие браузеры и ничего не вышло. Пробовал даже косвенно проверять, брал json переменную и записывал в куки и потом в другую переменную клал куки и проверял на наличие одной строки(без вывода просто что бы если строка такая есть в куки вывелось бы "yes") Но в итоге вообще ничего не работает. Помогите в чем моя проблема с этими куками и что можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы открываете этот файл как локальный, тогда проблема в том, что куки не могут быть установлены для протокола `file:` (иначе для всех локальных файлов они были бы общие), нужен внешний адрес с доменом, к которому куки будут привязаны. Попробуйте запустить этот же код в консоли DevTools на сайте, скажем, http://example.com/, и у вас должно всё получиться.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую! Но все таки странно что у многих в интернете это получалось и так сделать. Так же странно что у меня это в safari тоже удалось сделать

Comment: Иногда отдельные браузеры делают исключения из общепринятых правил. Возможно, в Safari разрешены куки для локальных файлов. А другие люди в интернете могли пользоваться каким-нибудь простым бесплатным хостинrом вроде GitHub или запускать локальный HTTP сервер и с него возвращать файл.